# Pasar varias variables de varios tipos de controlador a vista codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Buenas tardes,

genero la siguiente consulta a la base de datos para traer una lista con el id y el nombre de un producto

```
function getActivos(){
     // armamos la consulta 
     $query = $this->db
                ->select("*")
                ->from("tipo_activo")
                ->order_by("id_tipo_activo")
                ->get();
     // si hay resultados 
     //echo $this->db->last_query();exit; 
     if ($query->num_rows() > 0) { 
     // almacenamos en una matriz bidimensional 
        foreach($query->result() as $row) $arrDatos[htmlspecialchars($row->id_tipo_activo, ENT_QUOTES)] = htmlspecialchars($row->nombre_tipo_activo, ENT_QUOTES); 
        $query->free_result(); 
        return $arrDatos; 
        } 
    }
```

en el controlador tengo la siguiente función para cargar el resultado de la consulta:

```
public function modificar($id=null)
    {
        //obliga a que se le pase un parametro por la url, que es el id del activo a modificar
        if(!$id){show_404();}
        $datos=$this->activo_model->getTodosPorId($id);
        if(sizeof($datos)==0){show_404();}
        //print_r($datos);exit;
        // obtenemos el array de activos y lo preparamos para enviar 
        $getdatos['arrayActivos'] = $this->activo_model->getActivos(); 
        //print_r($getdatos);exit;

        $this->layout->view("modificar",compact('datos','id', 'getdatos'));
    }
```

y en la vista cargo la lista de la siguiente manera:

```
<p>
                    <label for="tipo_activo" >Tipo Activo:</label>
                    <select name="tipo_activo" class="form-control" value="<?php echo set_value_input(array(),'tipo_activo','tipo_activo')?>" autofocus="true" >
                    <option selected value="0"></option>
                    <?php foreach ($arrayActivos as $i => $nombre_tipo_activo) {
                        echo '<option value"',$i,'">', $nombre_tipo_activo,'</option>';
                    }
                    ?>
                    </select>
                    </p>
```

El problema que tengo es que cuando llamo la vista desde el controlador como relacione anteriormente:

```
$this->layout->view("modificar",compact('datos','id', 'getdatos'));
```

no me carga la lista de la consulta que realice, encambio,  si la realizo de la suiguiente manera:

```
$this->layout->view("modificar",$getdatos);
```

si me la carga,  pero no lo puedo dejar asi porque tambien nesecito cargar $datos y $id  que se estan cargando con un compact,  si lo cargo asi:

```
$this->layout->view("modificar",$getdatos, $id, $datos);
```

tampoco me funciona, que puedo hacer para cargar las tres variables y que me cargue la lista??

muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Revisa el array que envías a la vista con `var_dump( compact('datos','id', 'getdatos') )`, ademas prueba reemplazar `compact()` con `array_merge()` para juntar varios array. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres pasar los 3 parámetros sin ningún problema puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera, en una variable con el mismo nombre pero con distintos `arrays` internos.

```
$data['id'] = $id;
$data['datos'] = $this->activo_model->getTodosPorId($id);
$data['getdatos'] = $this->activo_model->getActivos();
```

y para pasar a la vista esos datos lo haces con:

```
$this->layout->view("modificar",$data);
```

Para accesar a esos datos en la vista únicamente mandas llamar la variable `$id`, `$datos` y `$getdatos`, cada uno es independiente.